# I can see what is in the subform, but others can't

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform in form which is created from two linked SQL tables. I run the subform from a query. I have 2 left joins in these tables. Then I have multiply expression of two columns, each column from one table. Then I run it, everything works fine, but other can't open the subform. *The error code is like this:*
**Access this expression is typed incorrectly or it is too complex to be evaluated. for example a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements...**

Comment: clearly more information is needed if no one has even commented for two days.  By others can't see subform I assume you mean in their front ends?  What are you linking to? Excel, SqlServer?  Anyway, whatever the structure the error tells you what to do in this case.  Find a way to simplify the forms datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Often this will fail as the database starts to grow as well.  Don't be afraid to use those complex queries but just create a static temporary table.  It will ultimately be faster (lookup in a table vs multiple query calls) and easily bypass these complex embedded calculation calls.

PS
Sometimes I would create ComplexQueryA, then ComplexQueryB would use that as the datasource and do another calculation etc, but ultimately when my final results were done I would always dump into a static table otherwise the application would be way too slow!